# operation of two computers on an single IP address

Tags: home-networking

how can i operate two computers on an single IP address?

Comment: We need more detail. Are you trying to run two machines using an Internet connection with one public address (i.e. a home network), trying to run two separate servers/services off one address, trying to run one service (on a single) using two machines (for load balancing and/or fail-over), or something else entirely?

Answer (score 5):

IP addresses must be unique within the network, therefore you cannot have two computers with an identical IP.

Unless of course, the question is how to share an Internet connection with another computer, such that they are both seen on the Internet as having the same IP address.

Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Get a router which will use one public ip address and give each client (computer, network printer,...) a private ip-address.

In your case, the router will provide both your computers with a private ip-address, probably something like 192.168.0.100 and 192.168.0.101